# How are Box API Mini object types defined?

Tags: json, box-api

I did a ctrl-f for "mini" through the entire [Box API documentation](http://developers.box.com/docs/), and couldn't find out where the mini types were defined. So, how are the mini object types defined? What fields do they contain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Great question.   We don't specifically document what makes up a "mini" format of each object.  Sounds like a great improvement for us in our docs.

As it stands now, the only way to know is to look at the examples.  The mini always contains the id of the object, the type of the object, a convenient displayable name, then depending on the object, possible an extra field or two.

```
{
    "type": "user",
    "id": "17738362",
    "name": "sean rose",
    "login": "sean@box.com"
},
```

Comment: Okay, thanks. I would definitely appreciate it if you added the complete mini type definitions to the documentation.